# Printer problem

Tags: 14.04, printing

I have just been prompted to upgrade Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS. Having done that the printer will not print, it just goes into the print queue. It works fine in Windows. Any suggestions welcome

Comment: Please edit your question to include printer model and any other relevant information like error/warning messages (if any) etc.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to be sure to do all updates and rebooting before making any other changes. I've discovered that Update Manager does not always report all necessary updates and it is important to press check first to make sure that the pending update is complete.

If the problem persists after doing that, I advise going to the printers section under System Settings, removing the printer, and then re-adding the printer.